# Open GI on button click

Tags: acumatica

I have created a button placed on PO line items grid and a new GI. I need to open these GI and automatically pass PO Order number as a parameter to GI.

I have written below code in button event handler. However, it is opening GI inside the inner frame (see screenshot) instead of in the main window.

```html
public PXAction<POOrder> viewFullSODemandGI;

        [PXButton()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Full SO Demand", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Insert, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Insert)]
        protected virtual IEnumerable ViewFullSODemandGI(PXAdapter adapter)
        {
            var poOrderNbr = string.Empty;
            foreach (POOrder current in adapter.Get<POOrder>())
            {
                poOrderNbr = current.OrderNbr;
            }

            var sURL = PXUrl.ToAbsoluteUrl(HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(string.Format("~/?CompanyID=Company&ScreenId=GI000092&POOrderNumber={0}", poOrderNbr.Trim())));

            throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(sURL, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, false, null);
        }
```

[image]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the biggest difference between the 2 approaches (one suggested by @Brendan and the other one originally used by @Krunal) is how URL is composed:

- @Brendan suggests a relative URL
- @Krunal composed an absolute URL

I had exact same result as @Krunal with absolute URLs. However with the relative URL composed by either of code snippets below, the task was successfully achieved:

- using GI name (Inquiry Title):

  ```
  string inqName = "InvoicedItems";
  var url = new StringBuilder(PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL).Append("?name=").Append(inqName).ToString();
  throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, true, null);
  ```
- using Generic Inquiry ID (Guid of a GI from database):

  ```
  string inqID = "6b267dbb-0ff2-49b2-b005-355c544daba3";
  var url = new StringBuilder(PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL).Append("?id=").Append(inqID).ToString();
  throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, true, null);
  ```

It's also worth checking the `PXRedirectToGIRequiredException`:

- using GI name (Inquiry Title) with a parameter (SalespersonID):

  ```
  string inqName = "SalespersonSales&SalespersonID=SP0003";
  throw new PXRedirectToGIRequiredException(inqName, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, true);
  ```
- using Generic Inquiry ID (Guid of a GI from database):

  ```
  Guid inqID = Guid.Parse("6b267dbb-0ff2-49b2-b005-355c544daba3");
  throw new PXRedirectToGIRequiredException(inqID, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.New, true);
  ```

Both samples for the `PXRedirectToGIRequiredException` can absolutely assign values to GI parameters.

Comment: good to know there is a constant we can use for the GenericInquiry (PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL). Thanks for Sharing Ruslan

Comment: You are welcome, Brendan! It's also worth switching to `PXRedirectToGIRequiredException` as shown in the updated answer above.

Comment: ah yes even better. Thanks again master jedi.  Looking at PXRedirectToGIRequiredException however it does not include an option to pass parameters? For this we would need to stick with PXRedirectToUrlException

Comment: Actually it's still possible to pass parameters with PXRedirectToGIRequiredException - check **using GI name (Inquiry Title) with a parameter (SalespersonID)** sample above

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. you are just injecting it :) we call it by ID. We created a class to auto set parameters easier and works well for us. Just updated to use PXGenericInqGrph.INQUIRY_URL. This is a helpful post for those using GI calls in the future. Thanks for posting the answer

Comment: Thanks Ruslan for sharing those options

Answer (score 0):

Change your window mode. I think you want to use InlineWindow. Also you can use the url just like this...

```
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(
    string.Format(@"~/GenericInquiry/GenericInquiry.aspx?ID=47842ccc-aa5d-4840-9d4a-7642cbf34cbe&POOrderNumber={0}", poOrderNbr.Trim()),
    BaseRedirectException.WindowMode.InlineWindow, 
    string.Empty);
```

Tested and loads in the current window without the menu extras.

I typically call Generic inquiries using the GI's guid "ID" vs screen ID as the screen ID might be different between Acumatica instances. You can get the ID from the export of the GI as the row "DesignID" value in the XML. Replace the ID value i have in the example with your GI DesignID value.

Comment: I have already tried that. It is opening in a new window. However, I want to open in same window.

Comment: I updated my answer after running a quick test. Use InlineWindow and call as shown in my answer.

Comment: It is still same, loading inside inner frame as shown in screenshot. Please note that custom button to load GI is on PO Line Item grid.

Comment: still testing this.. strange it does it with the code you have vs what I have. I also call the GI by ID and not screen ID as the Screen ID could vary from instance to instance

Comment: try using the different URL call for the GI. I have this working with your code (different GI of course) on the PO screen. Just replace the ID value in my example with the ID from yours.